# Facebook-connect gives a redirect loop

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

Please, I need help. I'm dealing with this issue for 1 month!!

I would like to implement facebook connect login to my website, using PHP and php-sdk 3.1.1. In few words, my code works offline (on localhost) but not online which results in "Too many redirect loop (on Chrome)": Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Here is my code:

1/ I load facebook connect SDK and init it:

```
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => '209633612480053',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ));
```

Please, note that I created two apps on facebook-developper page, one for offline tests, and the other for online tests. And I'm sure to switch correctly betwwen the two pairs of appId/secret (online and offline) when testing. So it's not the problem of bad facebbok-connect init.

2/ I try to get user info:

```
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();

  if($uid)
  {
     /*
      * Get user information.
      */
     $user = $facebook->api('me/');
     print_r($user); // Display user info.
  }
  else
  {
     /*
      * Redirect to FB login URL to allow access.
      */
     $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL();
     echo '<script> top.location.href=\''.$loginURL.'\'</script>';
  }
```

It's as simple as that: If user ic connected to facebook, so display it's information, else, redirect to facebook login page to allow access.

IT WORKS PERFECTLY OFFLINE, but online, I get a chrome error:

```
This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=209633612480053&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluward.com%2Foauth%2Ffacebook&state=551f60cd4be6cd8ed1622f8168a5219a#_=_ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
```

Some additional information: Online, I use 1and1 host provider, and to be sure to have the same server configuration than offline server (which is a MAMP Pro), I uploaded the sams php.ini file.

Please, if someone has an idea, or get a similar problem, I'll be glad to have help.

Thank you in advance for all help.

**UPDATE:**

I updated my code to focus on the problematic line, so instead of redirecting to facebook login page, I display the redirect URL, so I just have to click to login:

```
  $uid = $facebook->getUser();

  if($uid)
  {
     /*
      * Get user information.
      */
     $user = $facebook->api('me/');
     print_r($user); // Display user info.
  }
  else
  {
     /*
      * Redirect to FB login URL to allow access.
      */
     $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL();
     echo $loginURL; // <-- HERE I CHANGED THE CODE TO DISPLAY LOGIN URL
  }
```

What I noticed is that facebook is infinitely redirecting to my script page. Only `code` parameter on URL bar changes.

So, why facebbok is redirecting to my script page without giving me user info?

Please, any idea?

Comment: Have you enabled cookies in your browser?

Comment: Yes, of course. I use the setting that allow local data to be set (recommended).

Comment: strange then. place an exit after $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL(); and then update if it still redirects.

Comment: I updated my code. Now I just display the loginUrl instead of redirecting automatically. `$loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL(); echo $loginURL; // <-- HERE I CHANGED THE CODE TO DISPLAY LOGIN URL` But it still doesn't work!!!

Comment: Like $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginURL(); exit;

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work (I placed exit() after $loginURL). This gives me the login URL to click on. When I click, it redirects me to my script with (again) the login URL...

Comment: The given URL to click on is `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=209633612480053&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bluward.com%2Foauth%2Ffacebook&state=29f22cd0f394ff591b7d765b11d759e1`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11202/discussion-between-alphamale-and-hassinus)

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: I don't know if it can be usefull to you, but i made a module for kohana while ago, https://github.com/Faianca/Facebook-Connect and it was working properly. check it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem, in my case I had to edit base_facebook.php from the SDK:

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
);
```

The last two options I added manually.

Comment: genius had same problem with aredirect loop, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with chrome browser, cookies always were incorrect or empty.

Then I downloaded a facebook example from [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (it uses a popup window as login instead of a js redirect) and noticed that it doesn't work in chrome when the base URL of the website isn't the server root URL (ex: `localhost/somedirectory/`). 
But after creating a virtual host it looks like it works.

You can see an example of the index.php from the application here https://gist.github.com/2845986