# facebook login gives ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login, redirect, codeigniter-3

I am trying to log in with Facebook, but it gives me following error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

It was working perfectly some times ago, suddenly it gives above error.

Already tried with this answer: [Redirect-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573199/facebook-connect-gives-a-redirect-loop) but it didn't help.

Comment: If it stopped working end of March, then it is likely the API v2.2 shutdown. See duplicate for an explanation of what the issue is.

Comment: how to change the version? @CBroe

Comment: Depends on what SDK/library you are using. The PHP SDK v5 takes the API version to use as an initialization parameter, I think v4 already did as well. PHP SDK v3 did not allow to specify the API version, it is simply to old for that (was published before there even were different API versions.)